# How to insert output of strftime?

Tags: sqlite, strftime

I want to insert the output of the `strftime` in the column `Day_name`. It doesn't show any error message but it didn't insert anything:

```
INSERT INTO reviews(Day_name)SELECT strftime('%w', pub_date) FROM reviews;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to add to the table a number of records which is the result of a SELECT from the same table.
If the table is empty, the SELECT will return no rows, and you will be adding nothing.
On the other hand, if reviews had one hundred records, you would end up adding one hundred more.
If you want to insert a single value:

```
INSERT INTO reviews(Day_name) SELECT strftime('%w', pub_date);
```

EDIT:
Since what you really want is to UPDATE existing rows, then you should use the `UPDATE` command:

```
UPDATE reviews SET Day_name = strftime('%w', pub_date);
```

This syntax will update every row of the table.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually, the table is not empty.  But the problem is, pub_date column  is in the same table. and if I remove "FROM reviews" it tells me that it is unknown column.

Comment: I want to mention that "SELECT strftime('%w', pub_date)FROM reviews;" give me a result. I just want to add this result to my table.

Comment: I want to Update an existing column (Since I have created it earlier to add the output of strftime function)